# SQL Converting character to datetime

Tags: sql-server

Does anybody now how to convert this character to date or datetime:
'10022011'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick & dirty:

```
select convert(datetime, stuff(stuff('10022011', 5,0,'-'),3,0,'-'))
```

However, you might want to consider converting the string into ISO standard date format:

```
declare @d char(8)
select @d = '10022011'

select convert(datetime, substring(@d,5,4) + '-' + substring(@d,3,2) + '-' + substring(@d, 1, 2))
```

in order to avoid ambiguity.  10-02-2011 has different meanings depending on which side of the pond you are.

Comment: Moreover, the `-` are not necessary, so the expression can be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(datetime, STUFF(STUFF('10022011',3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'), 103)
```

the number at the end is the Sql format you want the date to output